# How to add a fixed string to a mongoDB result like we do we in SQL Server?

Tags: mongodb

We have this syntax with SQL server:

```
select name as 'database',
      'I_Love_SQL' as 'feelings'
from sys.databases
```

which will return results like this:

```
database    |   feelings
database1   |   I_Love_SQL
database2   |   I_Love_SQL
database3   |   I_Love_SQL
database4   |   I_Love_SQL
```

How can I achieve this with mongoDB? I have this query and I need to add some fixed fields for example ACTIVE, PT-BR, etc.

```
db.product.find({
    "company.cad": {
        $in: [" ", "14940"]
    },
    "tradeItemMeasurements.netContent.measurementUnitCode": {
        $ne: null
    }
}, {
    "_id": 1,
    "brandNameInformation.brandName": 1,
    "childTradeItems.gtin": 1,
    "company.cad": 1,
    "placeOfProductActivity.countryOfOrigin.countryCode": 1,
    "referencedFileInformations.uniformResourceIdentifier": 1,
    "tradeItemClassification.gpcCategoryCode": 1,
    "tradeItemDescriptionInformation": 1,
    "tradeItemMeasurements.netContent": 1,
    "tradeItemMeasurements.width.measurementUnitCode": 1
}).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)
to add calculated or constant fields to a query.

The [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)
stage appends new fields to existing result documents if you don't want to specify
a list of all fields. However, since your example projects a subset of fields you
can also [add new fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#add-new-fields-or-reset-existing-fields)
using expressions in a
[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

Your `find()` query would become a `$match` stage in aggregation. Here's an example showing a few different options (with comments) in the `$project` stage:

```
db.product.aggregate([

    // The initial $match stage can take advantage of available indexes
    { $match: {
        "company.cad": {
            $in: [" ", "14940"]
        },
        "tradeItemMeasurements.netContent.measurementUnitCode": {
            $ne: null
        },
    }},

    // Project the desired result fields
    { $project: {
        // Fields that already exist
        "_id": 1,
        "brandNameInformation.brandName": 1,
        "childTradeItems.gtin": 1,
        "company.cad": 1,
        "placeOfProductActivity.countryOfOrigin.countryCode": 1,
        "referencedFileInformations.uniformResourceIdentifier": 1,
        "tradeItemClassification.gpcCategoryCode": 1,

        // constant values
        "ACTIVE": true,
        "language.code": "PT-BR",

        // calculated values (in this case, size of an array)
        "itemCount": { $size: "$tradeItems" },

        // literal values (that might otherwise be interpreted as expressions)
        "batch.batchNumber": { $literal: 1 },
    }}

])
```